Mint from an existing contract
I have a coin already on the Solana chain and I want to list it on another chain kindly direct me on how I can go about it

I’m voting to close this question because the question is about Solana, not Ethereum

I’m voting to close this question because, as Lauri Peltonen mentioned, it is about Solana, not Ethereum. For Solana-related questions, you can post on Solana Stack Exchange.

Cross network communications are complex. You will need something similar to a bridge.
